# How do I change keyboard layout for just one user on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, keyboard-layout

> Note: I need a solution which preferably uses only the CLI.

I happen to have a nice new MacBook with a, here it comes, German keyboard. All my colleagues work with US keyboards.

Therefore, our Ubuntu 10.04 LTS servers are all set to US-keyboards. Is there a way to just set my own user account settings to a German keyboard layout without touching the system-wide keyboard settings or those of my other colleagues?

Isn't there an easy way to set that in `~/profile`, e.g. keyboard="de"?
(I am working without any Ubuntu user interface, just the command line.)

Answer (score 1):

> Note: you can do also this without a GUI using X-Forwarding over SSH...

I just finished installing Server.  You have to first install I guess keyboard utility.  To do so

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install x11-xkb-utils
```

To set the layout to German,

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
man setxkbmap
```

To get the correct syntax

Or you can look at `/usr/share/x11/xkb` or `/usr/share/X11/xkb/` respectively (e.g on 14.04)

Comment: So I can do that in the server version without a GUI?